# Save google maps to particular folder

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive, google-maps

All my google maps are saved to google drive's root catalog how to ask google to save them in `\Google Drive\travel` ?

Comment: … can't you just move them there? Or do you want to always save them there?

Comment: I suppose google maps application will be angry about that. I need somehow tell google where I have placed maps